# Mousdedown on multiple radio buttons in form

Tags: javascript, forms

This works whenever I click on a white space in my form (with .search-form as the class of my entire form)

```
 <form name="form" method="POST" action="/api/search.php" class="search-form" id="search-form">
   <input type="radio" name="role" data-role="wanted_specialty" value="1" class="radio-btn"><span class="overlay"></span> 1</label>
   <input type="radio" name="role" data-role="wanted_specialty" value="2" class="radio-btn"><span class="overlay"></span> 2</label>
   <input type="radio" name="role" data-role="wanted_specialty" value="3" class="radio-btn"><span class="overlay"></span> 3</label>
</form>




var form = document.querySelector('.search-form');
  form.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
    // DO SOMETHING
  });
```

But it doesn't work when I use that exact same code apart from the '.search-form' which is then changed by the class of all my radio buttons.

How can I make it so the "DO SOMETHING" works whenever any of all my radio buttons is clicked (or unclicked). It should be a filtering system with radio buttons with a live update how many results there are in the database.

Comment: `.addEventListener()` can only be used on a single element at a time. You will have to loop through your results and add the event listener to each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MouseDown is not supported on Firefox browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Events/mousedown

addEventListener can only be used on an element, not on an element group.

Try something like this :

```
var form = document.getElementById('search-form');
[].forEach.call(form.childNodes, function(item, iterator){
  item.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    //DO Something
    alert('click');
  });
});
```

https://jsbin.com/kusuyacoyo/edit?js,output

Comment: It doesn't recognize my click (or mousedown event). It just doesn't link to my API (which is in the //Do Something) whenever I click now.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Can the problem be that my radio buttons aren't directly child element from my form? (there are a lot of div's and labels in between the form and the actual radio buttons)

Comment: Yes that's probably the problem. I added a jsbin link with the given html code and it seems to be ok.